# Showing further divs and forms according to a select list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('select#type').change(function(data){
    if ($('input[name=type_id]').length){
        if ($(this[this.selectedIndex]).text().trim() !== "Category" || $(this[this.selectedIndex]).text().trim() !== "Articol"){
            $("div#type_id").empty().hide();
            $('#category').show();
            $('#article').show();
        }
    } else {
        if ($(this[this.selectedIndex]).text().trim() == "Category"){
            $('select[name=category]').change(function() { 
                $('select#type').val('Category').change(); 
                $('input[name=type_id]').val($(this[this.selectedIndex]).val()); 
                console.log('inside the selector of category');
            });
            $('#category').show();
            $('#article').hide();
            $("div#type_id").append().html('<label for="">Category id</label><input disabled type="text" name="type_id" class="form-control">');
            $("div#type_id").show();
            console.log('category: ' +data);
        } else if ($(this[this.selectedIndex]).text().trim() == "Articol"){
            $('select[name=article]').change(function() { 
                $('select#type').val('Article').change(); 
                $('input[name=type_id]').val($(this[this.selectedIndex]).val()); 
            });
            $('#category').hide();
            $('#article').show();
            $("div#type_id").append().html('<label for="">Article id</label><input disabled type="text" name="type_id" class="form-control">');
            $("div#type_id").show();
            console.log('article: ' + data);
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the HTML for the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Type</label>
    <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
        <option value="-">--</option>
        <option value="First">First page</option>
        <option value="Category">Category</option>
        <option value="Article">Article</option>
        <option value="Page">Page</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="category" style="display: none" class="form-group">
    <label for="">Category</label>
    <select name="category" id="input" class="form-control">
        <option value="-">--</option>
        <?php foreach ($category as $v): ?>
            <option value="<?=$v->id?>"><?=$v->name?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="article" style="display: none" class="form-group">
    <label for="">Article</label>
    <select name="article" id="input" class="form-control">
        <option value="-">--</option>
        <?php foreach ($articles as $v): ?>
            <option value="<?=$v->id?>"><?=$v->title?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="type_id" style="display: none;" class="form-group">

</div>
```

I want to make a jQuery script that detects when a specific value is selected from the `<select>` form with `name="type"`. In this case I want to detect whether “Articles” or “Category” is selected. If “Category” is selected, two more form fields are to be shown. When I select the value “Article”, only a `<div>` that contains a `<select>` with articles and the `<div>` that has `id="type_id"` are to be shown, and similarly if “Category” is selected.

The problem now is that when I select the Category and select the second element, it shows the article `<div>` and hides the `type_id` and if I select the third element from the select, it hides the `<div>` that contains the articles and shows `type_id`.

The article form doesn’t work at all; it shows but doesn’t show the `#type_id` and sometimes hides the category `<div>`, sometimes not.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Minimal Working Example?

Comment: There are a couple of things I see ?=$v->id?. Should not this be echo ?=$v->id?. Next name="category" id="input" and name="article" id="input". Why are you using same ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, few problems here.  First, you're reusing IDs, which is never a good idea.  You want to make sure that they're unique:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Type</label>
                <select name="type" id="selectType" class="form-control">
                    <option value="-">--</option>
                    <option value="First">First page</option>
                    <option value="Category">Category</option>
                    <option value="Article">Article</option>
                    <option value="Page">Page</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="divCategory" style="display: none" class="form-group">
                <label>Category</label>
                <select name="category" id="selectCategory" class="form-control">
                    <option value="-">--</option>
                    <?php foreach ($category as $v): ?>
                        <option value="<?=$v->id?>"><?=$v->name?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="divArticle" style="display: none" class="form-group">
                <label>Article</label>
                <select name="article" id="selectArticle" class="form-control">
                    <option value="-">--</option>
                    <?php foreach ($articles as $v): ?>
                        <option value="<?=$v->id?>"><?=$v->title?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="divType_id" style="display: none;" class="form-group">

            </div>
```

Next, assign reused values to variables so you're not traversing the DOM multiple times to access the same value.  Also, restructure your if/else tree for clarity.  If checking for a specific value, do it FIRST.  That way, if you hit the else block, you already know the condition is false.  For example:

```
if (variable != 10 && variable != 11){
    //do something
}
else if (variable == 10){
    //do something else
}
else if (variable == 11){
    //do another thing
}
```

Should be changed to:

```
if (variable == 10){
    //do something else
}
else if (variable == 11){
    //do another thing
}
else{
    //do something
}
```

You could also use a switch command and change the else to its default option, but I stuck with the if/else format you're using.

```
$("#selectType").on("change", function(data){ //not sure what "data" is supposed to have here that you want to write to the console, but leaving it just in case I'm missing something

var selectedOption = $(this).val();

if (selectedOption == "Category"){
    $("#divCategory").show();
    $("#divArticle").hide();
    $("#divType_id").innerhtml("blah Category blah");
    $("#divType_id").show();
}
else if (selectedOption == "Articol"){
    $("#divCategory").hide();
    $("#divArticle").show();
    $("#divType_id").innerhtml("blah Articol blah");
    $("#divType_id").show();
}
else{
    $("#divType_id").empty().hide();
    $("#divCategory").show();
    $("#divArticle").show();
}
});
```

Lastly, if you want to bind events to the elements that you're adding to the DOM, you need to do so AFTER they're added.  As your code stands in your post, you are trying to bind events to an element that doesn't exist - and THEN you're adding the element.  Reverse that!